# How to create random numbers a specific number of times?

Tags: java, loops, random

How can i create a random number a specific numbers of time?

```
public class Feld  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double k = (int)(Math.random()*1000001);
        int n = 1000000;
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0;i<n;i++){
            arr[i] = i;
        }
        boolean found = false;
        i=0;
        while (i < arr.length) {
            if (arr[i] == k) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (found) {
            i++;
            System.out.println(i);
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println((arr.length + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is, that if i put k into a loop to create it more than one time i'll get an error at:

```
if (arr[i] == k)
```

!!I just found out that i made a mistake explaining my problem. The array should be filled with values from 0-1.000.000 and i am supposed to print out the position of a random generated number for a specific amount of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have an array full of random numbers, I suggest using the following:

```
int n = 1000000;
int arr[] = new int[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    arr[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 1000001);
}
```

That will work and you don't even need the variable `k`.

---

**Edit:**

If you want to print at what position you find a specific value (for example `x = 543`), you can use the following code:

```
int x = 543;
int n = 1000000;
int arr[] = new int[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    arr[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 1000001);
    if(arr[i] == x) {
        System.out.println(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit2**

One possible solution to your new problem looks like this:

```
public class Feld  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 1000000;
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
            arr[i] = i; //Filling array with values 0-1000000
        }
        int number = 20;    //Print out position of a random generated number a specific amount of times
        int randomNumber = (int)(Math.random()*1000001); //The random number

        for(int j = 0; j < number; j++) { //Find number for a specific amount of times 
            for(int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) { //Find number in array
                if(arr[k] == randomNumber) { 
                    System.out.println(arr[k]); //Print
                    break; //Number found, don't have to search anymore
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: The array should always have a length of 1000000 but i have to but in different numbers of values and measure up how long it takes for them to be input like 10k values 100k, 1m, 10m ... what should i do with k and do i have to make another for-loop in this for-loop? The array doesnt have to be filled completely.

Comment: I just edited my answer. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I think it could work, it's just i am supossed to use the structure i have in my code above. Just that i fill the array with a specific amount of random numbers. And the numbers should be thrown through the algorithm. Than i have to measure how long it takes if i put 1 number, 10k, 100k, 1m, 10m into the array. I havent implemented the  code to measure the time yet. I wanted to do it afterwards, when the code works.

Comment: Ok. (1) To fill the array with a specific amount of numbers, you can use the first code snippet. You will just have to change the variable n to the desired number. (2) You will not be able to fill 10m numbers in an array of size 1m.

Comment: I know i was also wondering how it should work it has to be a mistake in the task.

Comment: One possibility would be to just overwrite values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214954/discussion-between-m-eichhorn-and-vulpini99).

Answer (score 0):

I would write a method that returns an array of random numbers and takes an `int` argument that defines the length of the array.

One possible solution is this:

```
public static int[] createRandomArray(int length) {
    // create an array of the given length
    int[] result = new int[length];
    // and use a single for loop that puts random int values into every index
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt();
    }
    // then simply return the result
    return result;
}
```

Try it as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // super primitive time measurement:
    // take the moment in time before calling the method
    Instant start = Instant.now();
    // then call the method
    int[] array = createRandomArray(1000000);
    // and take the moment in time after the method returned
    Instant end = Instant.now();
    // then calculate the duration
    Duration duration = Duration.between(start, end);
    // and print the duration in milliseconds
    System.out.printf("Array creation took %d milliseconds\n", duration.toMillis());
}
```

The result is the following output on my system:

```
Array creation took 10 milliseconds
```

Comment: The array-length is supoosed to be 1m but it doesnt have to be filled completely.

Comment: @M.Eichhorn you can insert 1000000 instead of 10 here... It will be filled anyway, because every index will be initialized with 0 if no different value is specified.